# LinearLayout onclick open WebView not browser

Tags: android, webview, onclick, android-linearlayout

I currently have 4 buttons, one will open a web browser using Intent.  I want to open the browser using webview.  I have seen the code for this but I am not sure how to implement it.

If I use this code:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

and change the xml file to include WebView, it adds this to the current home screen which I don't want.  I only want to use WebView once the user has clicked the button.  How do I do this?

xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/android"

>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/settingsScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    >

</ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Info"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Info"
        android:background="@drawable/button_colour"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Search"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Search"
        android:background="@drawable/button_colour"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Facebook"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Facebook"
        android:background="@drawable/button_colour"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Twitter"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Twitter"
        android:background="@drawable/button_colour"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

    />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
MainActivity:

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Search);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do as follows:

**your  activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/android" >

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/settingsScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"

>

</ScrollView>
 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/Info"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/Info"
    android:background="@drawable/button_colour"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Search"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/Search"
    android:background="@drawable/button_colour"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/Facebook"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/Facebook"
    android:background="@drawable/button_colour"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Twitter"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/Twitter"
    android:background="@drawable/button_colour"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

  />
```

**webview.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/webView1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**MainActivity**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Search);

   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
});
}
```

**WebViewActivity**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

}
```

Comment: I am getting this error message: The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<WebViewActivity>) is undefined

for this line: Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);

In MainActivity

Comment: use like this  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class); in MainActivity in button listerner

Comment: Thanks thats working well, however when I click on any website links from the URL within the WebView - it then opens a new browser instead of staying within the Webview

Answer (score 0):

You need to create seprate `Activity` then to show only `WebView` and pass `Intent Extra's` on `Button` Click:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/webView1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**MainActivity**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Search);

   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Url","http://www.google.com" )
        startActivity(intent);
     }
});
}
```

**WebViewActivity**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
String url;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    url = i.getStringExtra("Url");

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(Uri.parse(url));

}
```